# Delay in showing menus, tooltips, 3D cursor: Actually, delay in showing everything

Tags: 3d-cursor

So, where do I start.  When I click on a menu, what I expect to happen is to see the menu expand so I can see all the options.  You know, like every other program out there?  Instead, nothing happens - until I move the mouse over the area where the menu was supposed to be, and then the menu appears the way it's supposed to.

Tool tips have the same issue.  When I hover over a button or something, nothing happens.  Unless I move the mouse and it happens to move to the same spot that the tooltip was supposed to appear in.  Then I see the tooltip appear (usually very briefly).

One more example: I'll left-click to reposition the 3D cursor.  Nothing will happen.  If I sit there and wait, the 3D cursor will appear to remain exactly where it was before I moved it.  Unless I, for example, rotate the viewport or do some other action, and then the 3D cursor will magically appear in the new location (where I left-clicked earlier).

I'm using Windows 7, and this has happened to me in both 2.76b and in 2.77.  I tried both the 64-bit version and the 32-bit version.  I don't have a clue what's happening.

Anyone?  I'm just starting to get into Blender, and this is an increasingly major obstacle as I'm trying to learn some of the basics.

Comment: this sounds awefull, does it raise any error in the console when you start blender ?

Comment: If the problem were only with menus I'd think you have *Open on MouseOver* option checked in the User Preferences > Interface. However taking into account delay in *everything* this seems your CPU is in high overload and you're just waiting for its response. Check its load, e,g. with default task manager. And "tried both the 64-bit version and the 32-bit version" - this sounds pretty strange. The versions are supposed to be used on adjacent opeational systems; they won't work for both.

Comment: Yvain: Back when I was running 2.76b, I remember some error on startup that went away pretty quickly before I could memorize it.  Something about expected 44100 KHz but got 48000 KHz?  Anyhow, after opening and closing Blender a few times I never saw it again.

Comment: Mr. Zak: I don't have a dedicated graphics card, just the built-in Intel HD with Core i3.  But I ran a test with an OpenGL utility (OpenGL Extensions Viewer 4.3.6) and apparently it passed.  Besides, it can't be a CPU slowdown, because everything else is lickety-split - rotating objects and scenery, extruding faces, no delay at all.

Comment: But I'm starting to notice other issues.  When I use the menu to switch from Object to Edit mode, or when I use the adjacent menu to switch viewport shading, the screen doesn't update unless I click somewhere else. Oh - you know what else I've discovered which makes the screen update?  Moving the mouse out of the viewport window.  Weird.

Comment: But in any of these cases, it makes no difference whether I wait two seconds or ten minutes.  It's like the computer has done all the necessary calculations to draw the menu or reposition the cursor or what have you, but has decided not to do so until I do some other action.  Adding to the mystery, I just tried installing the same version of Blender on a different Win7 machine and it has no hiccups at all.

Comment: I think your problem may not be Blender related. How many processes are running when you start Blender, and what are the system specs, especially installed memory?

Comment: Intel Core i3 @ 2.4GHz, 4 GB memory, and I usually have other applications open but they don't seem to affect the other features of Blender. Besides, you'd think displaying a menu would be one of the least system-resource-intensive processes there is. And how come the delay lasts the exact amount of time between when I click the menu and when I move the mouse, whether it's two seconds or 15 minutes (I tested it earlier today)? By the way, I want to thank everyone for their patience - I realize this isn't a typical problem.

Comment: Okay, one more clue.  Usually it doesn't give me an error message when I exit, but the last time I closed it I got: "AL lib: (EE) ALCmmdevPlayback_mixerProc: WaitForSingleObjectEx error: 0x102"

Comment: I guess one more comment - I don't really want people to spend much more time on this unless they're incredibly curious or adventurous.  I can just use Blender on my other computer for the time being.  But I found an OpenGL diagnostic utility that I used to export some information about the graphics system in my computer.  I've posted the XML files at http://tinyurl.com/jpc6krx and whoever feels like looking at them, maybe that'll give some clues.  I also posted XML files from running the OpenGL utility on my 2nd computer (the one on which Blender is actually fully functional).

Comment: (continued) Not sure what else to try in terms of investigating.  I'll leave it to the real hardcore types after this point.  Of course, you can ask me about whatever other details you think could be helpful - I'll check back on this thread every so often.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a graphical issue, either from your GPU or graphics drivers; for this sort of problem you should always post what your graphics card is so it helps solving your problem.

You mention having no dedicated graphics processing unit, only an Intel integrated one, which are largely regarded as low end and known to often cause problems with blender, so that is most likely the origin of your problem.

Not exactly sure how to solve your graphical glitch, try upgrading your drivers to the latest version.

After that you could open blender, go to the *User Preferences > System Tab > Window Drawing Method* and play around with the options in the dropdown menu, see if any other besides the default one work better for your particular machine. Make sure you save settings and restart Blender in between changes.

Also try turning off any multi sample if it s turned on, in the menu right after the previous one.